# What is the need of 'goog.structs' when 'goog.object' is there?

Tags: javascript, object, struct, google-closure

What is it that `goog.structs` provides which `goog.object` does not?
I went through the documentation but didn't find anything satisfying, except the top line of `goog.structs` saying:

> Generics method for collection-like classes and objects.

What is a collection-like class or object in javascript? As far as I know, about javascript every object satisfies being 'collection-like'.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

[`goog.structs`](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/namespace_goog_structs.html) is a namespace containing a wide variety of specific classes for specific things, like [`CircularBuffer`](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_structs_CircularBuffer.html), [`Trie`](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_structs_Trie.html), [`Queue`](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_structs_Queue.html), [`Set`](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_structs_Set.html), and so on. `goog.object` is a fairly basic container.

Comment: I don't see any evidence of it being secret. To get the above, I searched for "Google Closure Library documentation", followed the link, expanded "Documentation" on the left-hand side, clicked "API Reference," and clicked `structs` on the right-hand side. That gave me the first link above, which lists the classes.